# Send Solana Transaction directly to the current and next Leader (0.5 SOL bounty)

Tags: web3.js, transactions, send-transaction, versionedtransactions

I need to send a transaction directly to the scheduled validator bypassing the rpc. Solana has upgraded to using QUIC, so I need a nodejs client that I can use to send transactions directly to the validator.

Before you could be able to do it like this:

```
var bh = await (await tpuConnection.getLatestBlockhash({commitment: "confirmed"}))
console.log(bh)
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let tx = new Transaction();
    tx.add(SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: from.publicKey, //from is my wallet keypair
        lamports: ranmax(10000, 15000), //random amount of lamports between 10000 and 15000
        toPubkey: new PublicKey("6fixxgrowcL162MojthGHZf3Tt5dHy8zPjpEN1ULYXyE")
    }))
    tx.feePayer = from.publicKey
    tx.recentBlockhash = bh.blockhash
    tx.sign(from)
    const signature = await tpuConnection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())
    console.log(signature)
}
```

But since the QUIC update this doesn't work anymore.

The purpose of my task is to be able to send transactions fast and make sure that they will be processed in the next possible block at a scheduled time. I don't want to be spamming the network with 1 sec before with transactions, to make sure that my transaction lands, I would like to send just 1 at the right time in the first available block. Any ideas or hints to documentation are very welcome.

Comment: Does [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6055/1202) help?

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but there is no mention of how to update the package and I would like to do it in node, not rust. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, QUIC support in Node isn't in great shape. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38478 is still in development, and https://github.com/fidm/quic is archived. Maybe you can get one of these to work, but you're probably better off just rewriting your JS logic in Rust and using the Rust QUIC client

Comment: Thanks man, yeah it seems that there is no way to do it with node at this time. Will look into Rust.

Comment: Jon C can you provide me an example of how can this be achieved in rust?